# Stubbing tests when using Ruby Mechanize

Tags: ruby, screen-scraping, mechanize

I've been trying to use Mocha to do some stubbing for tests on code using Mechanize. Here is an example method:

```
  def lookup_course subject_area = nil, course = nil, quarter = nil, year = nil
    raise ArgumentError, "Subject Area can not be nil" if (subject_area.nil? || subject_area.empty?)
    page = get_page FIND_BASIC_COURSES
    raise ArgumentError, "Invalid Subject Area" unless page.body.include?(subject_area.upcase)
    form = page.form_with(:action => 'BasicFindCourses.aspx')
    if !quarter.nil? && !quarter.empty? && QUARTERS.has_key?(quarter.downcase) && year.is_a?(Integer)
      form['ctl00$pageContent$quarterDropDown'] = "#{Time.now.year}#{QUARTERS[quarter]}"
      puts form['ctl00$pageContent$quarterDropDown']
    end
    form['ctl00$pageContent$subjectAreaDropDown'] = subject_area
    form['ctl00$pageContent$courseNumberTextBox'] = course if (!course.nil? && !course.empty?)
    result = form.submit(form.button_with(:name => 'ctl00$pageContent$searchButton'))
    result.body.downcase.include?(subject_area.downcase) ? result : false
  end
```

So the get_page method will return a Mechanize::Page with the html parsed and all that good stuff. I'd love it if someone knew a way to take that object and do something like a serialization of it (however, serialize did not work due to one of the sub modules of Mechanize::Page not understanding how to do a dump from Marshalling the object). What I've been having to do, obviously due to my lack in understanding of stubbing, is:

```
should "return a mechanize page with valid course subject" do
  Mechanize::Page.stubs(:body).returns(FIND_COURSE_HTML)
  Mechanize::Page.stubs(:form_with).returns(message = {})
  Mechanize::Form.stubs(:submit).returns(true)

  assert_equal Mechanize::Page,  @access.lookup_course("CMPSC").class
end
```

The above code is a work-in-progress, because as I was doing it I realized there HAS to be a better way and hopefully one of you smart guys out there has already done this type of thing. I don't want to have to stub out every bit of functionality. Ideally, I'd like to be able to create a Mechanize::Page object with html (since I'll know what the html will be on these pages... and that would be a good stub I think). None the less, I could not figure out how to instantiate a Mechanize::Page with html.

Could anyone guide me in a better direction to testing a method like lookup_course that uses lots of pieces of functionality. Maybe I should break up the logic in my code to make this better (if so, how would you suggest?)

Thank you for your time,

Michael

Comment: One solution I have used to circumvent the chaos of stubbing Mechanize itself was to design a skinnier interface around using Mechanize... I've created my own get and post methods that wrap Mechanize get/post, so that I can have my code decoupled from Mechanize as much as possible. Still interested in seeing if there are other ways of testing Mechanize for Ruby... Thanks for viewing though.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at this [Stakoverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151827/how-to-test-a-ruby-application-which-uses-mechanize) which suggests using [Fakeweb](https://github.com/chrisk/fakeweb). Another one worth checking out is [Webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock).

Comment: Just a note: Webmock doesn't yet support Mechanzie.