# Read a local HTML file with Mechanize

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I am building a crawler, I know how to use ruby mechanize to read a page from the net using this code:

```
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.get "http://google.com"
```

But can I use Mechanize to read an HTML file from the file system? How?

Answer (score -8, accepted):

IMHO it doesn't make sense trying to use mechanize for such a situation. Maybe you would like to parse HTML. Then try [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) (mechanize uses it for parsing too)

e.g. use

```
Nokogiri::HTML(open('index.html'))
```

instead of

```
session.get('http://www.google.com')
```

Comment: Thanks for your speedy reply, I fully understand the benefit of using nokogiri, in fact mechanize usees it too, but there are some methods already built in with mechanize without any extra coding with nokogiri... so I am hoping to see if it can be done?

Comment: I don't get how you would like to interact with a static HTML file. Maybe if you update the question we can help further

Comment: ok, I had another look at nokogiri, I think it covers all I need now, thanks!

Answer (score 39):

just using the file:// protocol worked great for me:

```
html_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
page = agent.get("file:///#{html_dir}/example-file.html")
```

and about the raised question why someone would use mechanize to read local html files: I found it necessary for testing purposes - just store an example file locally and run your rspec against it.

Comment: Using `File.dirname(__FILE__)` was giving me 404 error.But what did work for me is doing this instead: `page = agent.get("file:///#{Dir.pwd}/example-file.html")`

Answer (score 4):

I was unable to get the `file://` protocol to work correctly for me. Instead I used [Fakeweb](https://github.com/chrisk/fakeweb) by saving a web page locally and registering the URI

```
stream = File.read("saved_google_page.html")
FakeWeb.register_uri(:get, "http://www.google.com", :body => stream, :content_type => "text/html")
```

and having Fakeweb return it behind the scenes with a normal Mechanize process

```
agent = Mechanize.New
page = agent.get("http://www.google.com/")
```

See [How to test a ruby application which uses mechanize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151827/how-to-test-a-ruby-application-which-uses-mechanize)

Comment: Nice tool, and I also struggle with using `file://` - now is the question: why?!

Answer (score 2):

Basing on @Stephens answer; as `fakeweb` wasnt updated for a longer while and the maintainer situation is unclear, here an answer working around the issue using `webmock`, for whoever is in a hurry:

```
require 'webmock'
include WebMock::API

WebMock.enable!
stub_request(:get, "www.example.com").to_return(body: File.read("page.html"))

agent = Mechanize.New
page = agent.get("http://www.example.com/")

# ...
```